# CSS: The use of the top element does not work for me

Tags: css

I want to position my element according to top and not according to margin-top but the default is top = 0 and I try to change and fail only using br

```css
.hover {
  color: #fff0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, gold 50%, #fff 0) var(--_p, 100%)/200% no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  transition: 3s;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  max-width: 23.2%;
  margin-left: 120px;
}

.h1 {
  top:100px
}
```

```html
<div class="h1">
  <h1 class="hover">
    <div>Hi,</div>
    <div>I'm Opal</div>
    <div>Welcome to my site.</div>
    <!-- <span class="h1">&lt;h1&gt;</span> -->
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please send full example in codesandbox?

Comment: yes i will do it

Comment: @PriyenMehta Please: https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-haze-bbpn0f?from-embed
I want to download the text below using top

Comment: @PriyenMehta One is required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Fix that first. A `<h1>` element cannot contain a `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

When you always want to change the placement of any element, you must first or change its position to either **relative** or **absolate**, then control the element by properties(top, bottom, left, right) look to this example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>position: relative;</h2>

<p>An element with position: relative; is positioned relative to its normal position:</p>

<div class="relative">
This div element has position: relative;
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

another example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
} 

div.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>position: absolute;</h2>

<p>An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed):</p>

<div class="relative">This div element has position: relative;
  <div class="absolute">This div element has position: absolute;</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do following:

```
.h1 {
     position: fixed; 
     width: 100%;
     margin-top:100px;
}
```

When using `top`, you have to specify the position.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about CSS positioning to understand that because The top CSS property participates in specifying the vertical position of a **positioned** element. **It has no effect on non-positioned elements**.

you can learn about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top)

it's important to learn about CSS position because the element will behave differently in each position.

```css
div.a {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

div.b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border: 3px solid blue;
} 

div.c {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<p>red div element has position: relative;</p>

<div class="a">
  <div class="b">position: absolute, and top: 0.</div>  
  <div class="c">position: absolute, and is placed 50 pixels from the top of its parent.</div>
</div>
```